# Layer detection in a crystal structure

Tags: python, crystallography, atomic-simulation-environment, monte-carlo, atomistic-simulation

### Context

I have two images from a Monte Carlo Basin Hopping where silicon (in yellow) is getting replaced by germanium (in blue). Both have 32 germanium atoms at Si/Ge = 2.5; only the Ge distribution is changing.

There appears to be a clustering of the germanium in the the first structure with relative energy= 0 ev.
Whereas the higher energy structure has no such pattern.
I am trying to to correlate the energy and the clustering.

### Question:

How could I verify this layering/clustering, to correlate the energy and the clustering, using some sort of metrics?

Any of the following would be helpful for me.

- Any links to any publication to gain ideas
- Suggestion of a metric or parameter.
- Any ML method or software that may help with this.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the [ATAT software](https://www.brown.edu/Departments/Engineering/Labs/avdw/atat/) it may help.

Comment: @Camps Thanks, I have new to ATAT, would you care to explain a bit about how this may help?

Comment: Would he "care" to?

Comment: @Saha_1994  Literally all of your questions that have gotten answers are still left without any tick marks selected ! Would you mind taking a look at all your questions and mark the answers that answers your questions as accepted answer? This is the way this community is driven.

Comment: @VandanRevanur there is a tick mark on this one: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/9373/5 but none on the others. I agree that it would be better for the user to interact more with his questions.

Comment: I must have missed that. Most of the questions that at least show on the top questions on the user profile showed them without the green. I must have said “most of your questions” instead.

Comment: @VandanRevanur I have done it. Thanks for suggesting that. Anything related to this question, you have?

Comment: two suggestions on the metric: (1) entropy, get probabilities from 3D histogram; (2) number of the shortest Ge...Ge paths of length (number of bonds between the atoms) 1, 2, 3, 4...

Comment: @IvanChernyshov thanks for suggestions

Comment: @IvanChernyshov there's 4 close votes and 1 more will close the question. Would you like to expand your comment into an answer? The author of this question would probably appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

It would be suggested to use **molecular descriptors** such as Distance matrix, Randic Connectivity Index, Wiener Index, etc as metrics to differentiate the two states.

In order to understand the concept of molecular descriptors, refer to presentation [link](https://www.academia.edu/download/30818009/RTodeschini.pdf) and Chapter 3 *Molecular Descriptors* of book *Challenges and Advances in Computational Chemistry and Physics* (COCH,volume 8).

There are few softwares for calculation of Molecular descriptors of a system, one of them is **PaDEL-Descriptor**. Refer to paper: [link](https://doi.org/10.1002/jcc.21707) to know more about the software.